# Creating a running tally in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to take a spreadsheet where a balance is entered into a field and have that balance copied and added to all previous balances to create a running tally. I've tried it a few ways and I've looked at suggestions on other sites, but have not found something that works. I'm also trying to do the tally as part of a macro button, which clears the form when clicked. I even tried just doing it as a sequence of events but thats not really working either.

Here's the gist of it:

```
(a)5 (entered by user)
(b)5 
(c)0
(d)5


copy a to b
clear a
b+c=d
clear b
copy d to c
```

I'm sure theres a way better way to do this, any feedback would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple 2-cell approach that uses **A1** as the user-input cell and **A2** as the accumulator cell.
Enter the following *Event macro* in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range, A2 As Range
    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    Set A2 = Range("A2")
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, A1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        A2 = A2 + A1
        A1.ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

When you type a value in **A1**, that value is automatically added to **A2** and **A1** is cleared.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**